# get all sended and recived emails address programmatically in android

Tags: android, email, gmail, android-contacts

If you use google calendar and create a new event you see an option 'invite' a friend, you can select from all email address in Gmail not matter that's contact email or not. I see permissions of the app and I just see contacts permission.
my question is how can I achieve that?
note that I want all email address in Gmail account not just contacts emails addresses.
appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

All email addresses you see in your `Gmail` are actually contacts on your phone, usually you don't see them in your `Contacts` app because of group-visibility settings, but if you open your `Contacts` app settings, look for the "`display options`" or "`Group Settings`" options, you should see a list of sync accounts, and within your `Google` account turn on the "`Others in <google-account>`" group, you should then see those contacts/emails too.

To see a list of all emails currently on your phone whether they belong to a "*real*" contact or not:

```
String[] projection = { CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA };
Cursor cur = cr.query(CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
   Log.d(TAG, "found email: " + cur.getString(0));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention but I try your way and it does not show me all email addresses I use in my Gmail. In google calendar, if you try Google calendar and send just one email to an address you can see it in suggested address for invite people.